# Formato de cadena de texto se manda mal en Servicio Web

Tags: c#, webservice

estoy haciendo un curso de Servicios Web con C#, pero me pasa algo raro al momento de guardar un registro en un documento *.txt, y es el siguiente.

Mando el texto siguiente:

```
   Mesaje de Texto 3
```

Y en el *.txt me lo imprime de la siguiente manera:

```
   2021-03-18 14:16:56 >>> 3en56aje 18e Prueba 3
```

No encuentro motivo por el que lo guarde así.

```
    public static void Logs(String Nombre_Archivo, String Descripcion)
        {
            string Directorio = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logs/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();

            if (!Directory.Exists(Directorio))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Directorio);
            }

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Directorio + "/" + Nombre_Archivo + ".txt", true);

            string Cadena = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" + " >>> " + Descripcion);

            sw.WriteLine(Cadena);
            sw.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El formato que estas enviando a la llamada  `DateTime.Now.ToString` no está correcto, estas incluyendo la cadena que quieres guardar, dentro del argumento de la función y eso no es correcto, ten en cuenta que la función `DateTime.Now.ToString` sustituirá "d" por el dia, "M"por el mes, "y" por el año, "h"por la hora "m"por los monutos y "s"por los segundos; por eso la cadena (no Mesaje de Texto 3 como planteaste en tu pregunta) si no Mensaje de Prueba 3 se convierte a `3en56aje 18e Prueba 3`.

```
public static void Logs(String Nombre_Archivo, String Descripcion)
        {
            string Directorio = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logs/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();

            if (!Directory.Exists(Directorio))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Directorio);
            }

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Directorio + "/" + Nombre_Archivo + ".txt", true);
            //El elemento + " >>> " + Descripcion, debe ir fuera del argumento.
            string Cadena = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")+ " >>> " + Descripcion;

            sw.WriteLine(Cadena);
            sw.Close();
        }
```